# How save canvas state to db?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

So I built this real-time drawing app with node.js, socket.io, and html5 canvas. Every pixel that the mouse is moved while clicked is tracked and broadcast (to display drawing input on other computers).

I know it is possible to save an image of the canvas but this canvas is very large (10000x10000+ pixels). Right now, when the page is refreshed all the drawings are gone (as it was just send over a socket, nothing saved).

I would like to save all the canvas data to a db and then somehow rewrite it when the page is loaded again, but it is simply too much. How would you go about doing this??

Answer (score 1):

You can track the clicks and mouse moves that made the canvas look that way while you're sending them over the socket, and simulate them to rebuild the image.

Comment: That would be a database entry for every single pixel of a mouse stroke once a millisecond. I'm not sure if thats even possible. I need a more efficient method.

Comment: @Alley you don't have to submit every single one of them every milisecond. You can write them to the db every few seconds or so, and maybe, if you don't mind some quality loss, only keep a pixel every few, and suppose they had lines connecting them (think connect the dots).

Comment: Hmmm, do you think that would even work on an extremely large grid?

Comment: @Alley frankly, I have no idea. But this is the best I can think of right now, and it sure is better than the other options you have so far. If I find something better, I'll let you know.

Comment: k, thanks. I was thinking that that would work only if I had some type of dynamic loading where it only loads what would be visible on the screen, then the rest when scrolled. The only problem is that is kinda complicated to do

Comment: ... but we can make a small calculation: let's say the db is hit with a bunch of pixels (let's say ~100, encoded in a SVG-like markup -- there's no need to have an individual entry for every single one of the pixels) every two seconds. I think a db can take that.